# How to spec validates_uniqueness_of in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

How does one do this? Couldn't find any examples online... (using `rspec 2.5.0` & `rails 3.0.5`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it in `shoulda-matchers`: http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames

Answer (score 6):

```
before(:each) do
  @attr = { :bar => "foobar" }
end

it "should reject duplicate bar" do
  Foo.create!(@attr)
  duplicate_bar = Foo.new(@attr)
  duplicate_bar.should_not be_valid
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exactly what you are looking for, but you could check the error messages after the `save` or `update`

```
@widget.save
#untested, but this should be close
@widget.errors.full_messages.include?("validation message you are looking for").should be true
```

But honestly, this is probably not something that you need to test in your unit tests (if that is where you are placing them).  You are basically duplicating unit tests that Rails has already done for you.  It would be more appropriate to check for the error message in the view in a cucumber integration test.